# How to manage coherence data between local java program and remote Database

Tags: java, database, synchronization, offline

I'm developing a Java program, that runs on 3 machines.
These machines can add, remove, and modify data autonomously offline, to achieve data sharing and storing between clients I wanna use a remote DB with remote internet connection.

How I can implement this, is there any java framework to syncrhonize date in Offline/Online environment?

Comment: Looking for a library to do sync is more appropriate on the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) than here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Spring Sync library: https://spring.io/blog/2014/10/22/introducing-spring-sync

It's a start but doesn't do everything yet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll try your suggest